# Alternative derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

I am well aware of the form:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{df}{dx}$$
However, what of the form:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
Does it have any meaningful real-life interpretation? Thank you very much guys.

Comment: What happens when you calculate it for simple functions such as f(x)=x?

Comment: Well of course, it yields the derivative, but there is a singularity from the components that did not 'cancel' out. Like taking f(x)=x, you end up with $$1+\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{2x}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: Would that mean that it has no meaning?

Comment: if the derivative at $x$ exists, the second converges only if $f(x) = 0$ and in that case it converges to $f'(x)$. if $f(x) \ne 0$ and is continuous at $x$, the second always diverges.

Comment: In which case, you're referring to $f'(x)=0$? Like a trivial case?

Comment: @KeithAfas If $x\ne0$, then $1+\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{2x}{\Delta x}=\pm\infty$, depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative. If $x=0$, then it's equal to $1$. In other words, it almost always diverges.

Comment: @KeithAfas What we would like to tell you here is that your expression does usually not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delta f = f(x+xf-xi)+f(x)

Therefore in your case the positive sign changes the whole meaning of this expression and hence it is no longer a derivative. A derivative works because you are subtracting away the function in order to just have the change by itself....it would not make sense to add the function. Think about this graphically...if you added the function to the change in the function you would just have a larger function.